# Where to Free Memory Without Causing Error

Tags: c++

I am implementing an insert/search on a tree structure and I run into problems with freeing up memory.  When I include "delete currentNode" at the end of the code just before the return statement, I encounter this error shortly after running:

```
Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption
```

When I do not include delete currentNode, my program outputs the search results for longer than if I did "delete" before producing a segmentation fault. I am wondering where I need to deallocate the memory for currentNode so that I will not run out of memory.

Here is the code:

```
bool myEntry::search(Node *root, char *target)
    {
        myEntry::Node *currentNode = new myEntry::Node;

        currentNode = root;

        while(*target != '\0')
        {
            if((*target-97)== -53) myEntry::index = 27;
            else    
            {
                myEntry::index = *target++ - 97;
            }

            if(!currentNode->forward[myEntry::index])
                return false;

            currentNode = currentNode->next[myEntry::index];
        }
        return (currentNode->correct);
    }
```

Comment: `Where to Free Memory Without Causing Error` Generally: In the destructor of a smart pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating memory for a new `Node` object, but never use it. Instead, you instantly overwrite the pointer to the new object with a pointer to `root`.
When you call `delete currentNode`, you don't delete your new object, but whatever `currentNode` is pointing to at the end of your function.

So instead of `myEntry::Node *currentNode = new myEntry::Node;`, just write `myEntry::Node *currentNode = root;`.

This way, you don't allocate any memory, so you won't have to free any.

Answer (score 1):

When you set `currentNode = root;`, you lose the reference to the new Node you created, resulting in a memory leak.